# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! when coverting dictionaries within list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe, however, I got `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Below is an example and how I got the data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Decode the JSON data into a dictionary
scrapped_data = response.text
```

Content of `response.text` is:

```
[{"id":123456,"date":"12-12-2022","value":37},{"id":123456,"date":"13-12-2022","value":38}]
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe format like the following:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 12-12-2022 | 37 |
| 123456 | 13-12-2022 | 38 |

I tried the following methods:

`df = pd.DataFrame(scrapped_data)`

`df = pd.DataFrame_from_dict(scrapped_data)`

`df = pd.DataFrame(scrapped_data, orient='columns')`

all got the same value errors.

I also tried:

`df = pd.json_normalize(scrapped_data)`

but got **NotImplementedError**

The type for scrapped_data is string format

Thanks for your help, let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason for receiving this error from `pandas` is providing `str` as data. I think your data come as `str`, If it is the case then Try this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

orignal_data='[{"id":"123456","date":"12-12-2022","value":"37"}, {"id":"123456","date":"13-12-2022","value":"38"}]'
scraped_data = json.loads(orignal_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=scraped_data)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, scrapped_data is a string then you need to convert it into a dictionary (with the method loads from the json library for example).

If scrapped_data = '[{"id":"123456","date":"12-12-2022","value":"37"}, {"id":"123456","date":"13-12-2022","value":"38"}]',
then you can just do df = pd.DataFrame(scrapped_data).

Comment: I tried, but got the `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` which I don't know why.

Comment: I said that you needed to convert the response.text before (as Niyaz did)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it in the first place. Thanks for the help.